# Select top 5 rows in mysql database table randomly

Tags: mysql

I want to select the first 5 rows in my table randomly. For instance I have a table with a thousand rows now I want to select row 1 to row 5 but not in an ascending but random

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT  * FROM table LIMIT 5 ORDER BTW RAND()") ;
```

But I always get an error. Please anyone with a better idea

Comment: What is the error message? preplace "BTW" (What ever it is) with `by`

Comment: that is `ORDER BY` and limit range always in last

Comment: @Jens the error is caused because I used LIMIT  before ORDER BY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LIMIT then RAND rather than RAND then LIMIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648076/limit-then-rand-rather-than-rand-then-limit)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by sub-query, filter your required data in sub-query and shuffle by main query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5) _t ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I don't want to  select random from all row and pick 5 rows,  I want to select the first 5 rows and randomize them

Comment: @user7713452, what is base of first 5 rows?

Comment: @Girish for instance the first 5 rows from my query has the id of 2, 5, 7, 8 and 9 now when I run it in a while loop and echo the id, I want it to echo randomly

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your idea should work.

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5`

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-random-records-database-table.aspx